# ApplicationContext not getting set in Camunda's LazyInitRegistration class

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-plugin

I am using Camunda 7.17.0 and Spring boot(starter parent) 2.6.7
The LazyInitRegistration class from Camunda's spring boot starter webapp core jar is an ApplicationContextAware class. However the setApplicationContext method is not being invoked. As a result the LazyDelegateFilter's delegates are not being created which eventually throws NPE.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hm. Difficult without concrete code. Can you share a repo link?

Comment: @JanGalinski sorry for the late response. I fixed it. Actually in my custom spring Configuration class, there was an Import CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration class. This is no more required.

Comment: @JanGalinski I found a strange thing with Camunda 7.17.0 vs 7.10.0. If I create a Spring Configuration class like MyConfig and use ``` @Import(CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration.class) ``` , then the @Bean or overriden methods dont get executed. The only method which gets executed is camundaBpmWebappInitializer(). Other methods like resourceLoaderDependingInitHook, addResourceHandlers, addViewControllers dont get executed. This does not happen in 7.10.0. As a result the Camunda Cockpit throws NPE because of the issue addressed as part of this question. Can you please help?

Comment: Auto-Configurations are treated differently by spring, I also noticed strange behavior when mixing auto-configs via import. Try to stick to autoconfiguration or disable the particular auto-config and provide your own beans (could require c&p of code).
But I guess such very special questions and possibly bug reports are better addressed in the camunda forum or even camunda jira issues.